# Los elementos de Primefaces no cargan en otra pagina mas que en la principal

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, vistas

Este es mi codigo en la pagina prinicipal, aqui todo carga bien, los componentes y el funcionamiento de ellos es el correcto, estoy cargando un archivo y una vez que sea cargado quiero ir a otra pagina a descargarlo, pero no se que esta saliendo mal, adjunto mi codigo del index.xhtml en el siguiente bloque

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Hola Mundo JSF</title>
        <scrip language="javascript">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                function start() {
                    PF('statusDialog').show();
                }

                function stop() {
                    PF('statusDialog').hide();
                }
                //]]>
            </script>
        </scrip>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div class="card">
            <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status" draggable="false" closable="false"
                      resizable="false">
                <i class="pi pi-spinner pi-spin" style="font-size:3rem"></i>
            </p:dialog>
            <h:form>
                <p:fileUpload listener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true"
                              update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls)$/"/>
                <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
                <p:linkButton href="descarga.xhtml" value="Ir a descarga"></p:linkButton>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

y este es del la pagina secundaria, descarga.xhtml, a la que quiero ir cuando presiono el boton de "ir a descarga", pero cuando se hace la redireccion no carga nada, ningun componente, la pagina queda en blanco

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Hola Mundo JSF</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                function start() {
                    PF('statusDialog').show();
                }

                function stop() {
                    PF('statusDialog').hide();
                }
                //]]>
            </script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div class="card1">
            <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status" draggable="false" closable="false"
                      resizable="false">
                <i class="pi pi-spinner pi-spin" style="font-size:3rem"></i>
            </p:dialog>
            abc
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);"
                                 icon="pi pi-arrow-down" styleClass="p-mr-2">
                    <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file}"/>
                </p:commandButton>
                123
            </h:form>
            456
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Sale alguna información en el log del servidor?

Comment: El url de la página en blanco, es la del index o de la página de descarga? Que versión de primefaces usas? Si l das recargar a la página en blanco cambia o sigue mostrando en blanco?

Comment: La pagina en blanco es la de descarga, estoy usando primefaces 8.0, cuando recargo la pagina siempre queda en blanco.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado!

En la ruta de redireccion del componente en lugar de:

```
<p:linkButton href="descarga.xhtml" value="Ir a descarga"></p:linkButton>
```

Coloqué faces/ antes del nombre de la pagina redirecccionar

```
<p:linkButton href="faces/descarga.xhtml" value="Ir a descarga"></p:linkButton>
```

Esto creo que es debido a que en mi archivo web xml, lo tengo referenciado asi

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```